# Need help in determining what tests to run in SPSS

Tags: spss

I'm trying to find out whether there are any relationships between variables in my data set from Pew. I have two independent variables and one dependent.
My first independent variable comes from a question that asked parents of teen Internet users is they had ever: Used parental controls or other means of blocking, filtering or monitoring your child's online activities. 759 respondents (425 yes/325 no)
IV2- have you ever checked what websites your child visits? 759 respondents (588 yes/171 no)
My dependent variable comes from a question that asked the parents' children if they had ever withheld posting online for fear of how it would reflect on them. 764 respondents (460 yes/304 no). 
I recoded these variables so that yes=1, no=0, and don't know/refused answers are system missing. Now, if I want to see if my two independent variables have an effect on the dependent variable, what tests in SPSS should I run to find out?

Comment: Without more information about what these "results" are, how they were obtained, and what kind of "relationships" you seek, this question will just be too vague and broad to meet this site's standards of answerability.  Please feel free to make edits in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Since your dependent variable is binary i.e. you need answer in Yes/No, you can use either use logistic regression or Discriminant analysis to see which independent variable impacts the dependent variable most.

Here is a good [SPSS tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zYcMZ-61c4) for discriminant analysis and [logistic regression](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvQShzJ7Sns)

In addition to that you can also predict group membership.